# как показывать компонент только для авторизованного пользователя Vue Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, маршрутизация, аутентификация, sanctum

У меня реализована регистрация, авторизация и аутентификация через laravel sanctum. Если не ошибаюсь, то ларавел санктум авторизовывает через сессию.
**Также упомяну, что фронт и бэк написаны поотдельности**
Как мне сделать показ компонента только для авторизованного пользователя?
В моём случае если пользователь не авторизован, то я показываю ему один хэдер, а если авторизован, то другой

Comment: Так сяк я конечно могу навоять и оно будет работать, но я имею дело с этим впервые и очень интересует вопрос правильной реализации. Помогите пожалуйта

Comment: Вы же при аутентификации получаете токен и сохраняете его в куки, а потом принимаете данные о пользователя в локальное хранилище (через Vuex скорее всего)? Вот стягивайте принятый массив из vuex и проверяйте его существование. Если есть что-то — пользователь вошел, показывайте что надо пользователю.

Comment: Суть изложена в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authenticating) - вы авторизируетесь и получаете cookie, и потом делаете запросы на бэк. Можете делать его динамически для проверки что пользователь вошел, либо в самом cookie, либо [статически](https://shouts.dev/laravel-spa-with-vue3-auth-crud-example#step5) в Blade файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил вам хранить информацию о том, авторизован ли пользователь в сторе и получать её через геттер. А отталкиваясь от значения, возвращаемого геттером вы будете условно отрисовывать ваш компонент.

P.S. - Так же вы можете через следить за изменениями кук (например через `computed`), но для этого они должны быть реактивными, коими они не являются по умолчанию, но их можно сделать таковыми с помощью [этой](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-reactive-cookie) либы.

Comment: Я конечно успел уже прийти к этому решению, но большое спасибо) Это лучшее из ответов и того, что советовали в комментах)